# Mcrypt not detected with Laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I am trying to make a simple Laravel app.

It seems to be installed correctly but once I run:

localhost/codehero-laravel/public/

(the example code)

it shows the message: "Mcrypt PHP extension required."

It is weird because when I run php -m it appears mcrypt.

Also, if I run "$php --info | grep mcrypt"  it appears:

```
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

I tried everything I've fallen into, so please, can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: It's possible that the instance of php running in the command line is not the same as the one that is running on your webserver.  Check `phpinfo()` and make sure mcrypt is enabled there.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing - thanks @user3158900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your OS, you might have to create a symlink to mcrypt or move the .so file into another folder.

On Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Comment: That was it, I had several php versions in my computer and the one I was using did not have the mcrypt.so :S
Such a silly mistake, but it took me some time to realize it...